# Separate elements each cell in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have an R dataframe, with each cell set up in the following format : number (number, number), as follows

```
#create dataframe as follows
x <- data.frame("Col1" = c("0.4646 (0.4061, 0.7522)", "0.4137 (0.0178, 0.617)"), "Col2"= c("0.1996 (0.1383, 0.3499)", "0.9814 (0.7092, 0.9884)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x[1,1]
#"0.4646 (0.4061, 0.7522)"

#I want 0.4646 to go in a column called "Col1est"
#0.4061 should go in a column called "Col1lower"
#0.7522 should go in a column called "Col1Upper"
```

For each entry of x, I want to separate it into 3 columns. The request is represented in the code. How do I extract the specific values from the parentheses and put them in new columns?

~CEO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach reshaping data to long and using `separate_rows()` to get the values splitted. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newx <- x %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep = '\\(') %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(value=as.numeric(trimws(gsub(')','',value)))) %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>%
  mutate(name=ifelse(row_number()==1,paste0(name,'.est'),
                     ifelse(row_number()==2,paste0(name,'.low'),paste0(name,'.upper')))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Col1.est Col1.low Col1.upper Col2.est Col2.low Col2.upper
     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1    0.465   0.406       0.752    0.200    0.138      0.350
2    0.414   0.0178      0.617    0.981    0.709      0.988
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `map` to loop over the column names and `extract` the column into different columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(names(x), ~ x %>% 
     select(.x) %>%
      extract(!!rlang::sym(.x),
      into = str_c(.x, c('est', 'lower', 'Upper')),
     '^([0-9.]+)\\s+\\(([0-9.]+),\\s+([0-9.]+)\\).*', convert = TRUE) ) %>%
  as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Col1est Col1lower Col1Upper Col2est Col2lower Col2Upper
#    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   0.465    0.406      0.752   0.200     0.138     0.350
#2   0.414    0.0178     0.617   0.981     0.709     0.988
```

NOTE: This returns the correct column type

---

Or an option with `separate`

```
x %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(., '[(),]'))) %>%
   separate(Col1, into = c('Col1est', 'Col1lower', 'Col1Upper'), sep=" ") %>%
   separate(Col2, into = c('Col2est', 'Col2lower', 'Col2Upper'), sep=" ")
```

-output

```
#  Col1est Col1lower Col1Upper Col2est Col2lower Col2Upper
#1  0.4646    0.4061    0.7522  0.1996    0.1383    0.3499
#2  0.4137    0.0178     0.617  0.9814    0.7092    0.9884
```

---

Or using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = '[(),]', 
         replacement = "")], c('Col1', 'Col2'), sep=" ")
```

-output

```
#   Col1_1 Col1_2 Col1_3 Col2_1 Col2_2 Col2_3
#1: 0.4646 0.4061 0.7522 0.1996 0.1383 0.3499
#2: 0.4137 0.0178 0.6170 0.9814 0.7092 0.9884
```

---

Or using `base R`, we can use `gsub` with `read.table`

```
f1 <- function(colval) {
   read.table(text = gsub("[(),]", " ", colval), header = FALSE)
  }

out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(x, f1))
names(out) <- paste0(sub("\\..*", "", names(out)),
            rep(c("est", "lower", "Upper"), 2))
```

-output

```
out
#  Col1est Col1lower Col1Upper Col2est Col2lower Col2Upper
#1  0.4646    0.4061    0.7522  0.1996    0.1383    0.3499
#2  0.4137    0.0178    0.6170  0.9814    0.7092    0.9884
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format, extract the values in separate column and get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  extract(value, c('est', 'lower', 'upper'), '(.*)\\s\\((.*),(.*)\\)', 
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = est:upper, 
              names_glue = '{name}_{.value}') %>%
  select(-row)

#  Col1_est Col2_est Col1_lower Col2_lower Col1_upper Col2_upper
#     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1    0.465    0.200     0.406       0.138      0.752      0.350
#2    0.414    0.981     0.0178      0.709      0.617      0.988
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is an approach which uses the `tstrsplit()` function from `data.table`. It works without reshaping/pivoting for an arbitrary number of input columns:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
new_cols <- c("est", "lower", "upper")
setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) tstrsplit(x, "[(),]") 
                    %>% setDT() %>% setnames(new_cols))]
```

> ```
>    Col1.est Col1.lower Col1.upper Col2.est Col2.lower Col2.upper
> 1:  0.4646      0.4061     0.7522  0.1996      0.1383     0.3499
> 2:  0.4137      0.0178      0.617  0.9814      0.7092     0.9884
> ```

The output columns are still of type character. In case numeric output columns are expected the coercion can be included in the pipe:

```
setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) tstrsplit(x, "[(),]") %>% 
                    lapply(as.numeric) %>% setDT() %>% setnames(new_cols))]
```

> ```
>    Col1.est Col1.lower Col1.upper Col2.est Col2.lower Col2.upper
> 1:   0.4646     0.4061     0.7522   0.1996     0.1383     0.3499
> 2:   0.4137     0.0178     0.6170   0.9814     0.7092     0.9884
> ```